# OpenCV: imread gives CV_8UC3, can't convert to CV_8UC4?

Tags: c++, opencv

Need help with an image I try to load and convert with OpenCV:

Here is my code:

```
templ = imread("Template.bmp",-1);
cout<<"templ before convert: "<<type2str(templ.type())<<endl;
templ.convertTo(templ,CV_8UC4);
cout<<"templ after convert: "<<type2str(templ.type())<<endl;
```

This gives me always CV_8UC3! Is the image not made for converting to 4 channels or something like this? Or do I need a scaling factor (read about sth like this)?

Thanks for help,
best regards!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
cvtColor( src,dst, CV_BGR2BGRA );
```

Comment: It's as easy as that! Great! :)

Why did convertTo not help?

Comment: @Bl4cke4gle convertTo doesn't change the number of channels, it only changes channel type.